# Paint a coordinate system with different colors which are given in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, colormap

I would like to paint a coordinate system with customized colors which I give as an input.

```
Rmax=100;
Rxy=34;
x=[1:xmax];
y=[1:ymax];
Z=ones(x,y)*Rxy;  %this is the magic. first the map will be unicolor
imagesc(x,y,Z)
colorbar
set(gca,'clim',[1 Rmax])
colormap('cool')
```

With this I make a 500x500 map (xmax and ymax are 500) and color it with the Rxy value. I also put the colorbar next to the value and the map's color is the color which presents the value 34 on the colorbar.

Well, lets say I can count a value to every possible coordinate in the coordinate system, which means I will have an 500x500 matrix with different numbers. For every number I know a corresponding color according to the colorbar and I would like to paint that 1x1 square or point (i am not sure how this works) with that color, so in the end I will have a fully painted map with different colors.

Example: Z= [3 5 ;5 3]
Lets say 3 means green and 5 means red on the color bar. I have 4 dots so I have a 2x2 map with zero in the origo. So the map

```
              1
     this is  |  this is
      green   |   red
              |
 -1  -------  0 ------- 1
              |
     this is  |   this is
       red    |   green
              -1
```

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? Then the answer can already be found in your question.

```
testmap=[1 0 0; 0 1 0];
x=[-0.5 0.5];
y=x;
C=[1 -1; -1 1];
imagesc(x,y,C)
colormap(testmap)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also include the colorbar? And put the green and red (or whatever color you select from one of the colorbat) to the map with that?